# Power series related to Bernoulli numbers

Tags: power-series, bernoulli-numbers

I'm reading Tenenbaum's *Introduction to analytic number theory*.

He defines Bernoulli polynomials as the unique sequence $B_n$ such that

> $B_0=1$
>
> $\forall n\geq0, B_{n+1}'(X)=(n+1)B_n(X)$
>
> $\forall n\geq 1, \int_0^1 B_n(t) dt=0$

Tenenbaum writes

> One easily verifies that these assumptions imply the identity
>
> $\displaystyle \sum_{r=0}^\infty B_r(x) \frac{y^r}{r!} = \frac{ye^{xy}}{e^y-1}$
>
> (*for fixed $x$*)

How is that easily verified ?

For fixed $x$, I tried to write $B_{n+1}'(x)y^r=(r+1)B_r(x)y^r$ and then sum over $r$. $\sum_r (r+1)B_r(x)y^r$ is the derivative of some power series, but I can do nothing with $\sum_r B_{n+1}'(x)y^r$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote by $T(x)$ the LHS, so that 
$$T(x)=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} B_r(x)\frac{y^r}{r!}=1+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} B_r(x)\frac{y^r}{r!}
\tag{1}$$

Differentiating (1) with respect to $x$, we obtain
$$T'(x)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} rB_{r-1}(x)\frac{y^r}{r!}=
y\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} B_{r-1}(x)\frac{y^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}=yT(x)$$.

This is a classical linear homogeneous differnetial equation of
order $1$, so there is a univariate function $f$ such that
$$T(x)=f(y)e^{xy}\tag{2}$$.

Integrating (1) with respect to $x$ between $0$ and $1$, we see that
$\int_{0}^{1}T(x)dx=1$. If we integrate (2) on the other hand,
we obtain $\int_{0}^{1}T(x)dx=f(y)\frac{e^{y}-1}{y}$, so $f(y)=\frac{y}{e^y-1}$
which concludes the computation.

Comment: @ccorn corrected, thanks.